how can I verify the aircraft GPS is what TSO?
My understanding is that TSO-C 129() equipment and TSO-C 196() equipment are RAIM, and TSO-C145() and TSO-C146() are WAAS.
Although I can tell which RAIM/WASS an aircraft has -- by checking on the MFD, AUX, System setup page,  I have no idea which TSO-C equipment that GPS is. Are there any clue to figure it out?
Only thing I found is something mentioned in "G1000 Pilots Guide for the Cessna Nav3", and it says
"/G" may be filed for a flight plan. the G1000 system meets the requirement of TSO-C145a Class3 or TSO-C145c Class3 and ETSO-C145 class3 installations
Added comment.
Actually, a lot of people mention Aircraft flight manual or its supplement. However, when it comes to C172S-G1000, which I fly, I could not find anything mentioning TSO-C129,196,145,or 146, in a supplement book. Anyone know exact location stating GPS related to TSO-C in a handbook, aircraft manual or supplement? or whatever.

That's usuful source, but looks that 2.3 explains how to check what version of GPS the aircraft equip, not specifically mention how to check which TSO-C equipment the GPS is.

Each of the aircraft GPS require a POH/AFM supplement.  Inside this supplement, it will state what procedures are allowed to be used with this GPS.

TSO-c129 are non-WAAS receivers
TSO-c145 are WAAS compliant receivers

